# Print Methods with polymorphism. c++

Tags: c++, methods, polymorphism

I have 2 Classes that look like this:

```
class A
{
public:
A();
~A();

virtual void func() { cout << "this is A class" << endl; };
};
```

and:

```
class B:public A
{
public:
B();
~B();

virtual void func() { cout << "this is B class" << endl; };
virtual void funcky() { cout << "How to print this method?" << endl; };
};
```

and this is my main:

```
include "B.h"

void main()
{
A* a;

a = new B;
}
```

Now my question is how can I print the method "funcky"? (withot making a B object in main.)
I think its something with dynamic casting but I'm not sure.

Comment: You want to access a method from A's interface that does not exist in A's interface?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: [dynamic_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

Comment: Yes. I saw it once but I dont remember how to do it.

Comment: It's perfectly true that you can do this with `dynamic_cast`. But -- I'm just making the same point as Karoly Horvath here -- this seems very unlikely to be the best way to achieve what the questioner is *really* trying to do. Tomer Uzan, **why** exactly do you want to call `B::funcky` without having anything declared as having type `B` or `B*`?

Comment: beacuse my goal is to do it by polymorphism - to use only one object (A) and according to the user dynamically allocate another objects.

Comment: You can but don't (so question "how" is irrelevant). If you need to call this method, redesign your classes.

Comment: `void main`? `include`? ew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A preliminary remark: as `A` class is intented to be derived, it really should have a virtual destructor. If it has not, `A* a = new B; delete a;` will not call `B` destructor.

Then, even it it does not make much sense in such a simple example, what you want is *dynamic casting*. It is a bit hacky but is present in standard and makes sense when you decouple interface and implementation. When a method in implementation class receives a pointer to the interface, it uses dynamic casting to convert it to the real class and use private methods.

In your example you should simply use:

```
B* b = dynamic_cast<B *>(a);
if (b != nullptr) {
    b->funcky();
}
```

But when you find yourself using dynamic casting, you should always wonder whether you are not deviantly using polymorphism...

Comment: One can use `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast` if one is **absolutely certain** that the dynamic type of the object pointed to is (or derives from) the derived type you want to cast it to.